# Lookup using a key from a dropdown cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a dropdown that selects from several text "keys," like so:

List of items: `Pathetic,Untrained,Novice,Adept,Master,Amazing`

I'm trying to use these keys to run a lookup on a separate sheet, with the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP(R3,Calculations!B2:C7)
```

Where R3 is the cell with the dropdown, Calculations is the sheet in question, and from B2 to C7 the cells are like this:

```
| Pathetic  | 1 |
| Untrained | 2 |
| Novice    | 3 |
| Adept     | 4 |
| Expert    | 5 |
| Master    | 6 |
```

However, I only seem to be able to get it to return the number 6, the final value in the attempted lookup table. Am I missing an argument?

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` accepts a third and fourth argument as well. Try setting that to `2` and `0`.

Comment: Tried `=VLOOKUP(R3,Calculations!B2:C7,2,0)`, but same result.

Comment: If `R3 = 'Master'` then this would be the correct answer....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
=vLOOKUP(R3,Calculations!$B$2:$C$7,2,0)
```

For LOOKUP (as opposed to VLOOKUP) to work properly the data must be sorted.

The anchors (`$`) are in case say the formula was to be copied down (eg to return a value from R4). Without them the array range would slide down automatically until by R9 the search would be of Calculations!B8:C13.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! When you say the data must be "sorted," is that a more specific state that I have to inform the program of?